# std::copy equivalent in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have some code in C++ that use `std::copy` in these lines

```
std::copy(array1, array1 + 4, arrayV + i);
std::copy(array2, array2 + 4, arrayV + i + 4);
```

inside a unroll loop. All of arrays are `uint8_t*`. 
How can I transform these lines for equivalent code in C that will produce the same result?

Comment: Does `memcpy` fit the bill?

Comment: I tried to use memcpy for my case of this way memcpy(array1, array1+4, arrayV+i); but since array1 and array2 are const uint8_t * I get an error. Also I also get an error in the arrayV + i part. However the code works correctly in c ++, but I don't know how to adapt this correctly to code c. @sergeya

Comment: I strongly recommend reading [some documentation for `memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) before  throwing arguments at it.Very few things work properly if you don't know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

instead of

```
std::copy(array2, array2 + 4, arrayV + i + 4);
```

you do

```
memcpy(arrayV + i + 4, array2, sizeof(*array2) * 4);
```

If the memory blocks may overlap, you may use [`memove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove).

Comment: thanks, in this case: std::copy(array1,array1+4,arrayV+i); is correctly do memcpy(arrayV + i, array1, sizeof(*array1) * 4); ? or not? What would be the correct way in that case?

Comment: `std::copy()` may be *optimized* to use `memcpy()` internally for trivially copyable types, yes.